# How to generate the React client library based on role permissions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a CMS for a school project. It's required that some functions are  hidden/shown depending on the permissions which the logged user has associated with them. I want to be able to sort out the shown functions on the server side, so that a user cannot see disabled functions inside the client.js file.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: That seems to introduce unnecessary complexity (and isn't necessarily straightforward). What's the point of that? Why would this be needed? FWIW, this has nothing whatsoever to do with React in particular.

Comment: @FelixKling For security; I don't like the idea of sending my admin page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The added complexity of what you are trying to accomplish is neat in theory but not even a high concern for Department of Defense or defense contractors applications.

Sending or not sending that an endpoint does not really protect you against much. If a user is inspecting your JavaScript and trying to be malicious they probably know how to use patch inspectors to find out about the existence of endpoints you are trying to hide.

The added complexity of trying to build a dynamic version of client.js, and maintenance there of, far exceeds the gains of hiding the endpoint. The best way to secure the endpoint is to ensure that the endpoint does a authorization check and returns a 403 if the user does not have access to preform that action.

As far as application security this falls far below other major application hardening concerns, such as XSS and CSRF and proper server validation and authorization checking on the server. For a full list of real application security concerns and vulnerabilities I would suggest reading [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *not* doing this, but if you really want to:

If you use webpack/browserify you can try building 2 js bundles: 1 'normal' without the special functions and 1 'special' with them by specifying different entry points. This would require you to order your code in such a way that the special functions are never referenced from the 'normal' js.

You can create all sorts of solutions for this. Restructuring your complete code base, placing some sort of shim in place of your real code, swapping files before compiling, or devising some sort of a run-time loader for separate code.

If there is something in your code you really don't want non-admin people to see you are probably better of just reorganising your code so that there is nothing like that in there. Maybe some logic should be moved to the server?